# Jenkins workspace folder path is shown in double quotes and html-publisher plugin is unable to detect allure-report folder

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, allure

Trying to generate allure-report for my testng results in a Jenkins pipeline. For which I am using the allure-report maven plugin and publish-html Jenkins plugin. But the problem is the allure-report folder path is shown in double quotes (in the workspace folder structure):

```
"/vol_01/jenkins/workspace/Test Run/Sanity/core/target/allure-report"
```

That's why the htmlpublisher plugin is unable to identify the directory and is failed:

```
ERROR: Specified HTML directory '/vol_01/jenkins/workspace/Test Run/Sanity/core/target/allure-report' does not exist.
```

Even though I can open the folder and see the report properly.

**pom.xml** (snippet):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
  <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
  <version>2.10.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <reportVersion>2.13.2</reportVersion>
      <reportDirectory>${basedir}/target/allure-report</reportDirectory>                    
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**Jenkinsfile** (snippet):

```
publishHTML target: [
                        allowMissing: false,
                        alwaysLinkToLastBuild: true,
                        keepAll: true,
                        reportDir: 'target/allure-report',
                        reportFiles: 'index.html',
                        reportName: 'Allure Report'
                    ]
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be with an space character in the Jenkins folder name. Jenkins (with Maven site plugin) is creating a folder path in double quotes which is not handled properly.

Need to see if I can open an issue to get this fixed (or if already fixed in latest versions).